# Structure for loading different web references as a plug-in

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, web-reference

We have developed an application in C# .NET that synchronises data (customers, orders) to a PHP e-commerce application using SOAP.

The WSDL of the PHP application is added as a .NET 2.0 web reference to our application, so the .NET Framework generates classes and functions to communicate with the SOAP web service.
For instance, we are able to send stock information like this:

```
catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity stock = new catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity();
stock.is_in_stock = 1;
stock.is_in_stockSpecified = true;
stock.qty = "10";
webserv.catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate(sessionid, itemcode, stock);
```

This works fine, however we are frequently running in situations where one of our customers has additional (non standard) fields defined in the WSDL and wants this fields to be used in the synchronisation.
Our current practice is to create a new branch of our code for this customer and update the web reference to use the specific WSDL of our customer.

To prevent us from getting a long unmaintanable list of branches of our software, I'm planning to do a complete overhaul of the structure of our application. 
Now I am wondering what would be the best structure to handle this.  I was thinking to put the web reference in it's own class and load this DLL dynamically,  so if a customer has a non-standard WSDL we could create it's own class and load it as a 'plug-in' into our software. But the additional fields in (for instance) the catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate will then still not be available in the main part of our application.

Are there any tools that might help in achieving this? I would like to have one main application for synchronisation and put all customer specific mappings and references to the WSDL in a separate class/project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, for adding plugins support to your app you can use [Microsoft Extensibility Framework (MEF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx). If you're constrained to using .NET 2.0, then there are other custom ways for discovering and loading up plugins (through separate app domains, or by loading them straight to the primary app domain).

As for the design, I would make each plugin:

1. Hold the service reference to it's particular web service instance.
2. Make any particular assignments or logic to that service. For example assign `10` to `stock.qty`.
3. Provide callbacks/events the application could use to interfere with the logic implemented in the plugin. For example, you could have the plugins expose an event called `BeforeStockSubmitted` and you could do some validation or checks in the app on the data being submitted to the service.

Your plugin host (the application, or a module of it) should:

1. Expose a consistent object model for all plugins. You should offer a certain degree of abstraction for all entities the plugins will work with (such as `sessionId`, `stock`, etc).
2. Data coming into the plugins should be abstracted as well. So you can have an `IStockInfo` interface in the host and each plugin should be constrained to provide their own implementation. The host can populate the common properties of these objects while the plugin takes care of the specific part.